MWPM decoding with PyMatching in presence of measurement error
I am trying to do decoding in presence of measurement error and bit-flip error for the repetition code. In the PyMatching version 0.2.2 https://pypi.org/project/PyMatching/0.2.3/ it mentions that

To decode instead in the presence of measurement errors, each stabiliser measurement is repeated L times, and decoding then takes place over a 3D matching graph (see Section IV B of this paper), which can be constructed directly from the check matrix H using:

m = Matching(H, repetitions=L)


and then decoded from an m by L numpy array syndrome z using:

c = m.decode(z)

I tried this for an example case with H as the repetition code syndrome
import numpy as np
from pymatching import *

N = 10 # number of qubits
H = np.zeros((N-1,N),dtype = int)
for i in range(N-1):
    H[i,i] = 1
    H[i,i+1] = 1

and syndrome histroy
z = array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

but I am not getting the correct corrections. The weird thing is, even if I take no measurement error and bit-flip error and just repeat the syndrome, I get the wrong results so I think, I am doing something incorrect. Please help me with this.

As per the documentation, Matching.decode takes a syndrome array z which is read as if z[i,j] is the "the difference (modulo 2) between the measurement of stabiliser i in time step j+1 and time step j ".
This means that the row z[i,:] represents the detection events of the $i$-th stabilizer through time, not the syndrome at timestep $i$.
Using m.decode(z.T) will yield the correct correction [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0].
Under the hood, pymatching does not check the shape (m,n) of z, only the number of values in z i.e. m*n (see the function _syndrome_array_to_detection_events in this file, at line 190).

Thank you clarification. Does the decoder also take into account of qubit error (I am assuming it does for measurement)?

c tells you the correction that need to be applied to undo the (deduced) qubit errors. Pymatching just compute a minimal-weight perfect matching that pairs detection events. If a pair links two events at the same time step, it is a deduced qubit error and added to c (mod 2), if it links two events at the same location across two time steps, it is a deduced measurement error and is ignored in c since it had no impact on the qubits. Pymatching always care about qubit errors and will take measurement errors into consideration if you set repetition > 1 and z is 2D.

thanks that make sense. I have another minor doubt on how to handle the boundaries. I seems like since we don't include Z1ZN parity check, it's not correcting for boundary errors? I understand that in their documentation, they do mention that it can handle boundary single site defects.

On the contrary, you do correct potential boundary errors, as both $Z_1Z_2$ and $Z_{N-1}Z_N$ can be solely flipped by a single qubit error (on qb $1$ and $N$). Adding $Z_1Z_N$ would make the detector graph a loop instead of a path graph, so the boundaries would disappear.

If there's a error on first qubit, I understand that you get non-trivial detection for $Z_1Z_2$ but not for $Z_{N-1} Z_N$. Or are we assuming that boundaries $N$ and $1$ operator are same.

I forgot a word in my comment. One error on qubit 1 flips only $Z_1Z_2$, one error on qubit $N$ only flips $Z_{N-1}Z_N$. Feel free to ask a separate question if this is unclea.r

Hi, I posted a separate question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/40079/22078 Can you please check on that

I'm not accepting the answer because if you use Matching.from_check_matrix(H,repetition= L) and then m.decode(z.T) I'm getting the size error.

In particular, the check condition z.shape[0] * z.shape[1] == self.num_detectors appear to cause issue here. Since the number of syndrome are equal to $N-1$ which are not equal to $(N-1)L$

These details are not part of the question though. People are not omniscient, so there is little chance anyone could have helped you with that

I cannot reproduce the issue you mention with from_check_matrix, so you might want to include the whole code in one block. $N-1$ is the number of stabilizers which are measured $L$ times. The syndrome is usually the collection of measurement outcomes (aka detectors) hence it is of size $(N-1)L$.
