PyMatching in presence of qubit error for the repetition code
I'm considering the repetition code in presence of measurement and qubit error as discussed in SEC IV B of this paper. I am trying to use pymatching for the syndrome decoding using mwvp in presence of qubit error, so it should work but it doesn't. First, I defined the basis setup
import numpy as np
from pymatching import Matching
N = 10 # num of qubits
H = np.zeros((N-1,N), dtype = int) # check-matrix

for i in range(N-1):
    H[i,i] = 1
    H[i,(i+1)] = 1

Consider the following syndrome measurement :
L = 10
z = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

Here z[:,i] represents the syndrome measurements at time $t = i$. The decoding can be done as follow:
m = Matching(H, repetitions=L)
c = m.decode(z)
np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8)

but the corrections are incorrect. On the other hand, if I just take the final syndrome at $t = L$ then
m = Matching(H)
z = z[:,-1]
c = m.decode(z)
np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)

which in fact the correct correction operators. I want to know why does the repetition approach gives the wrong result, and way to improve upon that. Thanks

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong in either case. You do not state what you expect the correction to be in the first case. If you expect the correction to be $0$ everywhere, it means that you read the syndrome row by row instead of column by column:

Vertices are stabilizer measurements, red vertices correspond to the syndrome, lines are potential qubit errors. The matching is in red, with $25$ deduced qubit errors, most of which cancel each other since Pauli errors are Hermitian operators.
The column on the left indicates the sum modulo 2 of the qubit errors.
The deduced correction is exactly array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8).

As I mentioned in my question, when generating the syndrome, I didn't induce any measurement errors. Is there a way to incorporate that into the decoder? Because it looks like, it has deduced measurement errors which aren't there?

@Himanshu See my edits. It was not clear to me from your question that you had no possible measurement errors. They could be paired and replaced with neighboring qubit errors, which I did.

I suspect that as long as you use the repetitions parameter, pymatching will use measurement errors. In the absence of possible measurement errors, there is little point repeating the measurement. To ensure no measurement errors are deduced, you could have pymatching decode the $L$ syndromes separately and sum the deduced corrections modulo 2.

I tried to set space-like weight (which corresponds to zero qubit error) to large weights, but it doesn't  seems to be working. All I'm trying to see is that how does the repetitions improve upon the measurement error case. In other word, there's one case where you have a single shot and another where you repeat the measurement many times, but I'm not able to figure out
